# Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$, is it possible for $||A||>1$ for Euclidean norm $|| \cdot ||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-norms, spectral-radius

Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with spectral radius $\rho(A)<1$, is it possible for $||A||>1$ for Euclidean norm $|| \cdot ||$?

I'm working on a proof where we are given the fact that $\rho(A)<1$, and in the case of $A$ being symmetric we know that $\rho(A)=||A||$ for the Euclidean norm. I am trying to make the proof more general, for when $A$ is not symmetric. All I would need to show is that, if $\rho(A) < 1$ then $||A|| \le 1$.

My attempt here is to use the singular value decomposition and the fact that the 2-norm is invariant under orthogonal transformations. Let the SVD of $A$ be
$$U^\intercal A V = D$$

where $D$ is diagonal with singular values along the diagonal. Then
$$||U^\intercal A V|| = ||A|| = ||D||$$
Since $\rho(A)<1$ then the singular values are also less than 1, then $||Dx|| < ||x||$, hence

$$\sup_{x \ne 0}\frac{||Dx||}{||x||} < 1$$

Comment: The singular values don't have to be bounded by the spectral radius/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here's a counterexample, let
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $\{0\}$ thus $\rho(A) = 0$. However, for $x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ we have $\|x \| = 1$ and $Ax = \begin{pmatrix} a\\0 \end{pmatrix}$. Hence $\|A\| \geq a^2$. As $a$ is arbitrary we can make the norm of $A$ arbitrarily large whilst keeping $\rho(A)  =0$.

Comment: Wow, my big problem here was assuming that the singular values are always the sqrt of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Indeed, it is a common misconception to think the eigenvalues and singular values are so neatly linked. Once you move away from normal matrices their relationship is not so nice unfortunately.

Comment: Yes my prof actually came up with the same counter example and said the same how he has seen this come up a lot. Anyways I have found an interesting property where there always exists an induced matrix norm such that for any $\epsilon$,  $||A||<\rho(A)+\epsilon$. While it is not the Euclidean norm we can say that if $\rho(A)<1$ then we have some norm such that $||A||<1$.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Yeah, if you ever want to see if a property extends to non-normal matrices then check this matrix first. It's a super common counterexample, a good one to commit to memory :)
Also, cool!